# Loop through multiple tables to find match from table1 value

Tags: sql, oracle, join, select

I have 4 to 5 tables which can all be related to **Table 1**(ID)
Based on the value present in Table 1 "ID" column, I would like to loop through Tables 2, 3, and 4 to find a match. Once a match is found, I would like to extract one other column from that table. Any help?

[image: Table 1]

[image: Table 2]

[image: Table 3]

Expected Output (Once match found in either Table 2 or 3 )

[image: Output of match from Table 1 and Table2]

Comment: Your question has just two tables while you mention four, which makes things unclear. You would also need to show the result that you expect.

Comment: @GMB - Tables 2,3,4 are similar to Table 2 shown for representation

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm using sql developer

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, etc. Show what parts you are able to do. [ask] Clarify via edits, not comments. PS Why are you talking about "looping" in SQL?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please dn't change a question to invalidate reasonable answers. Post a new question. I have rolled this back. You can roll back my rollbacks but don't please don't change the question. Please also edit to improve per the comments & close message. PS This question shows no research effort either in solving or searching. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exists`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where 
    exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.id = t1.id)
    or exists (select 1 from table3 t3 where t3.id = t1.id)
```

If you want to display data coming from the other tables, than use `left join`s instead:

```
select t1.id, t2.col1, t3.cola
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
left join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
where coalesce(t2.id, t3.id) is not null
```

Comment: I've rephrased my question, with few pictorial representations. I hope my question is clearer now? Sorry for the confusions earlier

Comment: @ThomasKennedy: see my updated answer.

Comment: I've slightly updated the requirement and have shown what I have tried but do not want duplicates